# How can I bypass the 14 day old and 100 msg limit

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm trying to get around deleting 14 day old messages. I couldn't find anything on this topic for JDA, and I'm pretty stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [purgeMessages](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#purgeMessages(java.util.List)) instead. That method will not *bypass* the limit but will just handle it appropriately by deleting individual messages if they are too old.